# Ian Sommerville - Software Engineering - Requirements Engineering

Tags: requirements

I have a question about the structure of requirements. Ian Sommerville (Software Engineering 10th Edition, 2016) divides requirements into User Requirements, System Requirements, Functional Requirements and Non-Functional Requirements. Can I understand this structure in a way that user and system requirements are one abstraction level above functional and non-functional requirements?

Example:

```
1. user requirements
1.1 Functional requirements
1.2 Non-functional requirements

2. system requirements
2.1 Functional requirements
2.2 Non-functional requirements
```

Comment: In the classification you have presented (I don't know the book) they're not really "above" but orthogonal.

Comment: Ian Sommerville Page 120: `The user requirements for a system should describe the functional and nonfunctional requirements so that they are understandable by system users who don’t have detailed technical knowledge. `

Comment: "functional and nonfunctional requirements" just means "requirements" since all requirements are functional or nonfunctional

Comment: No, not all requirements are functional and nonfunctional. Requirements which are necessary for the system are functional, others are nonfunctional. (Words from sommerville)

Comment: Well if you read it as "requirements which are functional and nonfunctional" then it isn't talking about any requirements so they might as well just delete the whole sentence. But you would be wilfully ignorant. If the loudspeaker says "ladies and gentlemen, you may now queue to board the plane" do you stay seated because you are not a lady and a gentleman?

Comment: According to this classification scheme, they are orthogonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different ways of categorizing requirements. Without seeing the exact text that you are referring to (and Sommerville has written several editions of *Software Engineering*, with the most recent being the 10th edition in 2015, and then *Engineering Software Products* in 2019 as a replacement), it's not possible to explain exactly what the author means. However, I can speak about requirements engineering in general.

User requirements, system requirements, functional requirements, and non-functional requirements aren't equal levels of abstraction. There are different ways to categorize a given requirement.

Functional versus non-functional (sometimes called the "quality attributes" or "quality requirements" of a system) is one way. Functional requirements describe behavior, usually in the sense of inputs and outputs. Non-functional requirements describe the overall operation or properties of the system under design.

The distinction between user requirements and system requirements is more about the source of the requirements. User requirements specify what the users and customers expect from a system, in the context of the user's domain. System requirements exist in the solution domain and describe what the software must do.

Often, system requirements are derived from and traced to user requirements. Both levels of requirements - system and user - may have both functional and non-functional requirements. In that sense, yes, it's safe to say that system requirements are an abstraction over functional and non-functional requirements or that user requirements are an abstraction over functional and non-functional requirements.